# Storing the minimum event time for each user id in the same table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, min, row-number

I'm using snowflake to solve a problem. I'm trying to find the minimum event time for each user id and store it in another column in the same table.

For instance,

| user_id | client_event_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-08-04 |
| 1 | 2022-08-21 |
| 2 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-07-31 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 |

I want to store it like the following:

| user_id | client_event_time | MinEventTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-08-04 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-08-21 | 2022-07-28 |
| 2 | 2022-07-29 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-07-31 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 | 2022-07-29 |

I started with the following SQL query:

```
  SELECT user_id,client_event_time, 
    row_number() over (partition by user_id order by client_event_time) row_number,
    case 
        when row_number = 1  then client_event_time
     end as MinEventTime
    FROM Data
    ORDER BY user_id, client_event_time;
```

| user_id | client_event_time | row_number | MinEventTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 | 1 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-08-04 | 2 | Null |
| 1 | 2022-08-21 | 3 | Null |
| 2 | 2022-07-29 | 1 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-07-31 | 2 | Null |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 | 3 | Null |

I'm a little confused about how to proceed after this. I would also appreciate a suggestion on another approach. Thanks!

Comment: Can you format your input / output as a table? It's difficult to read.

Comment: Just formatted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use `MIN()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT user_id, client_event_time,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY client_event_time) row_number,
       MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) MinEventTime
FROM Data
ORDER BY user_id, client_event_time;
```